# Unable to get data on Other Route using REDUX & ROUTER

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I'm building up a website using ReactJS, REdux,React-Router.I want to access the data upon a different Route i.e for search functionality but I'm unable to do so. I'm only able to access data upon same page.

[My App Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdfS9.png)

[Home Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgVId.png)

I'm dispatching the Action from SearchComponent to store.
I want to access data on /Search Route but unable to do so.

Comment: It is unclear what any issue is or what you are asking. Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see what the code is doing, and include more specific details about any issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should point to the component in route element.

Add the component attribute to the route element, pointing towards the component that it should use when hitting the search route.

Remember to import the component first.